# The random function ranges from 1> 10, generating the number required

Tags: php

I have a random function between 1 and 100
I want it to random out 2 < x <10, x is the number I need, if x does not randomize the number in that range then continue random until satisfactory, how to write
Thank.

```
$x = rand(1,100);
if (2 < $x < 100){echo 'ok'; }

$x = rand(1,100);
if (2 < $x < 100){echo 'ok'; }
```

Comment: we want a clearer question and what you already tried

Comment: I have tried with the above code, it will stop if no output number I need

Comment: `rand(3,9);` seems a possibility, assuming I understood the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple while loop:

```
  $x = rand(1,100);
  while (2 > $x || $x > 10) {
    $x = rand(1,100);
  }
echo $x;
```

The above loop will only stop if your number is between your specified range (not sure if I understood your needs correctly).

Another approach could be to simply use a different interval for the rand() function.

EDIT: Please check the comments of your question, there is a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works well, have a nice day ^^

Comment: Please also check @RiggsFolly solution, it might be the better approach, mine seems a little overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

for (
    $i = 0, $limit = 10; 
    $i < $limit && $x = rand(1,100);
    $i++
) {
    echo $x, ' ', (2 < $x && $x < 10) ? 'HIT' : 'MISS', "\n";
}
```

Example output:

```
76 MISS
83 MISS
59 MISS
13 MISS
7 HIT
18 MISS
9 HIT
39 MISS
79 MISS
91 MISS
```